# How can I be sure I am not a victim of someone else's IP address ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have been banned from asking questions. But if you look at my profile I don't have very bad questions. I don't know why I got banned. How can I be sure that I am not a victim of someone else's IP address ban?

I did not see any warning.

Comment: Have you deleted any questions?

Comment: yes just 2 and i have undeleted them

Comment: I don't think the question asking ban is ever based on IP addresses

Comment: You have 4 questions with a score of 1, 15 questions with a score of 0 and 5 with a score of -1. We don't know the details of the question ban algorithm, but I wouldn't be surprised if you got question banned purely by your own questions.

Comment: they even did not gave me any warnings

Comment: is answering with good vote helps lifting question ban?

Comment: You haven't seen a warning like in the screenshot [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow/231118#231118)?

Comment: No i did not see any warnings at all

Comment: Undeleting all the questions linked in the answer here is NOT the right move, at least not without some editing first... I am refraining from being too aggressive with the downvoting on them, but I picked a couple randomly and I feel a LOT of them are still off topic...

Comment: @Pekka웃 They try to avoid it, but they have mentioned specific IP bans in extreme cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not blocked based on IP address, this is entirely based on your own questions. Sorry.

You have a series of deleted questions (all older than 60 days, two have a score of -1, all the rest have a score of 0). I can't imagine you are too deep into the ban; just follow the instructions on https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans (improve your existing questions) and be patient.

The full list of deleted questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290885/webapi2-status-code-500-messagean-error-has-occurred-with-no-detail
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561784/ef6-with-multiple-context-has-throws-model-compatibility-exception
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800561/memorycache-object-become-null
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539824/is-there-any-way-to-overload-primitive-types-operators
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010402/use-ef6-with-2-seperate-context-on-one-database
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672605/render-control-with-inline-code-blocks
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199340/cross-domain-json-jsonp-with-wcf-and-nullable-arguments-raise-error
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160446/whats-didependency-injection-and-where-we-should-use-it
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115558/solr-patternreplacefilterfactory-not-store
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946223/getting-error-on-updating-csv-file-into-solr-expected-fieldnames-in-csv-input
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812923/pars-json-from-google-map
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805184/how-to-find-what-is-the-native-code-and-the-version-code-of-ocx-file-for-decompi

Comment: So when OP said *"yes just 2 and i have undeleted them"*, he was mistaken/lying?

Comment: @Stijn: you can only see **recently asked** questions in the deleted questions list. Which is why I added the *all older than 60 days* qualifier. This is a common misunderstanding about what the deleted questions list shows you. For the OP the list is currently empty as they undeleted the two posts that were previously listed there.

Comment: So I can not undelete and improve them?

Comment: @PouyaSamie: I can give you a list if you want, and you can make your own decision.

Comment: it's the kind of you

Comment: I don't think immediately undeleting them all helps anyone… Especially without substantial edits. Perhaps there was a bit of a misunderstanding here on the purpose of providing this list?

Comment: @CodyGray: I gave the user a pointer to the "how do I get out of the ban" documentation, including explicitly pointing out they need to improve questions. It's now up to them; undeleting those posts without editing is indeed not smart, as these posts can now be voted on in *either direction*.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't trying to blame you personally.